# VBA Loop Copy cells from worksheets into master sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy

I'm fairly new to VBA and so looking for help.

I have a master sheet that I want to collate data gathered from other sheets in the same workbook, sheets 2-60. I would like to copy cell A4 of the first sheet into cell B3 and the data from cells K7:K42 into cell B4:B41. Then move onto the next sheet and insert the same data range into column D3 and D4:D41 and so on until all sheets have been copied.

This is what I have so far but as you can tell, this is going to be very long winded writing out the same two lines of code for 60+ sheets.

```
If myWs.Name <> "Master" Then

    If myWs.Name = "Sheet2" Then
    Sheets(myWs.Name).Range("K7:K42").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Range("B4")
    Sheets(myWs.Name).Range("A4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Range("B3")
    End If

    If myWs.Name = "Sheet3" Then
    Sheets(myWs.Name).Range("K7:K42").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Range("C4")
    Sheets(myWs.Name).Range("A4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Range("C3")
    End If

End If

Next
```

I have search SO for the last 2 days really and tried many things/code, but so far coming up short and very confusing.

Comment: Wayne, a couple of tips: 1) To reply to people in comments you need to prefix their screen name with @ ; 2) Use the [edit] link below a question to add additional content. It "gets lost" in a comment and cannot be formatted (looking at the `For Each...` here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim counter As Long

    counter = 2

    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> "Master" Then

            ws.Range("A4").Copy
            wsMaster.Cells(3, counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ws.Range("K7:K42").Copy
            wsMaster.Cells(4, counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            counter = counter + 1

        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub smth()

Dim myws As Worksheet, i As Long, ind As Long, col As Long

For Each myws In Worksheets

    If myws.Name <> "Master" Then

        ind = 0
        For i = Len(myws.Name) To 1 Step -1
            If IsNumeric(Mid(myws.Name, i, 1)) Then
                ind = i
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If ind = 0 Then GoTo nextWS
        col = CLng(Mid(myws.Name, ind, Len(myws.Name) - ind + 1))

        myws.Range("A4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Cells(3, ind)
        myws.Range("K7:K42").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Master").Cells(4, ind)

    End If
nextWS:
Next

End Sub
```

This code will check if your sheet name has numbers at the end and if yes it will use that number as the column to paste to.

Comment: Thank you for this, the answer above worked perfect but I thank you for your input. I did try your code as well and it pastes the first sheet into the mast sheet and then overwrites this data with the other sheets. Effectively putting all the data onto the same cells in master sheet.  But I thank you for your time.